# To execute modules as scripts in Catkin

Tags: ros, setup.py, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to run installed python modules as scripts in Catkin?

For instance, if you look at `moveit_joy.py` source from `moveit_ros_visualization` package, there are python files that contain classes ([e.g. this](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/527c0547b072e0d7e6a457fcd0fbfcc9613a3131/visualization/python/moveit_ros_visualization/moveit_joy.py#L65)) as well as [main](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/blob/527c0547b072e0d7e6a457fcd0fbfcc9613a3131/visualization/python/moveit_ros_visualization/moveit_joy.py#L607) (`if __name__ == "__main__":`), which tells me it's intended as both module and script.

```
$ dpkg -p ros-indigo-moveit-ros-visualization | grep Ver
Version: 0.6.5-0trusty-20160114-1001-+0000
$ rospack find moveit_ros_visualization 
/opt/ros/indigo/share/moveit_ros_visualization

$ rosrun moveit_ros_visualization moveit_joy.py
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named moveit_joy.py below /opt/ros/indigo/share/moveit_ros_visualization

# This module is callable as an argument for python interpreters. E.g.:
$ ipython /opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/moveit_ros_visualization/moveit_joy.py
Unable to register with master node [http://localhost:11311]: master may not be running yet. Will keep trying.
```

(For the particular package above, because the module installed via `distutils`/`setup.py` is not callable, it's [worked around by defining install rule in CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_ros/pull/584), which works fine but now we have duplicate python files in the installed space.)

---

**Update 6/23/2016** To [execute modules as scripts](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts), should I install python file as `script`, or `module` in Catkin?

**UPDATE 2022/09/07** Years later I came to my own post again. While this thread doesn't provide much reasoning for "Why is it bad?", sounds like encouraging re-use-ability by separating module and executable can be a propelling reason. See #q222258

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224546/to-execute-modules-as-scripts-in-catkin/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2016-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, you should not use that to install a module. I wouldn't mess with executing a module with a main section, instead just write a small wrapper script which imported the module and runs the main, then install it with `catkin_install_python()`

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [recommended way to install an executable Python script](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_python.html) uses the `catkin_install_python()` CMake command.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-06-23**:
Thank you, I wasn't aware of `catkin_install_python()` macro. I added a question to my original post; is `catkin_install_python()` recommended for installing a module that can also be called as an executable?